ROS 2 with Japanese language
I am creating a ROS 2 Network in MATLAB and I want my node names to be in Japanese. Although every time getting error that Japanese Characters are not supported. Is it only MATLAB specific? Or even by using CPP/Python, we cannot create ROS 2 Network having Japanese characters?

Try changing your system locale, and checking the encoding of your script. I believe utf-8 includes all languages
